# HQL Criterion with join

Tags: hibernate

I have a use case to display a list of entities using a subset of the values in the full entity.  The approach I have taken is to create an EntityList class with only those fields to appear in the list.  This class is mapped to the same table as the full Entity but with only a subset of fields.

Using HQL, I want to filter the EntityList returned based on fields that are in the full Entity.  In the example below, I want the EntityList filtered on the description field of Entity (which is in the table but not in the EntityList class).

```
public interface IThreePhaseMotorList {
abstract public Long getId();
abstract public String getMfg();
abstract public Double getPowerUnits();
abstract public Integer getPoles();
}

public interface IThreePhaseMotor extends IMotor {
public abstract Long getId();
public abstract void setId(Long id);
public abstract Integer getVersion();
public abstract void setVersion(Integer version);
public abstract String getIdsrc();
public abstract void setIdsrc(String idsrc);
public abstract String getDescription();
public abstract void setDescription(String description);
public abstract String getManufacturer();
public abstract void setManufacturer(String manufacturer);
public abstract Integer getPoles();
public abstract setPoles(Integer poles);
}
```

If I was writing SQL directly against tables it would look like:

```
Select IThreePhaseMotorList.* 
  from IThreePhaseMotorList JOIN IThreePhaseMotor ON  
      IThreePhaseMotorList.id = IThreePhaseMotor.id
  where IThreePhaseMotor.Description like 'test%';
```

Is there anyway to do this in HQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The approach I have taken is to create an EntityList class with only those fields to appear in the list. This class is mapped to the same table as the full Entity but with only a subset of fields.

This is the root of the problem. Don't do that. Just use the complete entity for your query. Loading some unneeded columns usually doesn't have any significant impact on performance. And if it does, then just execute a query which selects only the columns you want.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.  It does impact performance as the result set is sent via a web service and has to be marshalled into/out of XML.  I would prefer not to write a query in SQL since that will require significant maintenance of code for column mapping hence my question.

Comment: You're not forced to return a list of your entity from the web service. You can simply transform every entity instance returned by the query into a DTO object containing just the data you want to marshall and return from the web service. And where did I suggest SQL? HQL can be used to return properties, not just entities : `select foo.id, bar.name from Foo foo join foo.bar bar` for example. See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-select